# strange characters ^M php can not identify

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, specifications

I open a file (saved as ISO 8859-1) using the terminal (Ubuntu) and see where new lines should be the following character `^M` (surrounded by XX before and after).

Now, I run this code in php to see how PHP handles that:

```
$text=str_split($text);
var_dump($text);
```

in the var_dump I see only an array with size 4 and only the 'X' in it.
Any idea what is going on in there?

EDIT: open office translates this `^M` correctly to a new line.

ANOTHER EDIT:
The following code changes nothing. `echo str_replace("\r","XXXXXX",$text);`
I run this before the `str_split`

Comment: `^M` or `\r` is called "carriage return". It's often companion of the "line feed" `\n` on DOS/Windows or for network protocols. Some text editors display it only if it isn't used continuosly for *all* linebreaks.

Comment: `perl -p -i -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' somefile.txt` will convert the line endings if that's any use to you.

Comment: Or you can `sudo apt-get install dos2unix` if you prefer; it will do the same thing.

Comment: @El Yobo  the perl thing did not work, did you put there all the parameters? Do I have to put the output of that thing into a new file, or it changes the input file itself?

Comment: It changes the file directly.  You can pass multiple file names at the same time to convert amny of them.  How has it not worked, exactly?  If the problem is *only* that the file has DOS format file endings rather than Unix format, the script will solve it, but it won't fix anything else.  You could also try the dos2unix tool, but I suspect it's doing exactly the same thing on the inside.

Comment: @El Yobo - changed nothing in the file, I still see the ^M, regardless, I tried the same thing from within PHP and it should have work if this was a simple case of \r that needs to be replaced.

Comment: @El Yobo b.t.w if this intrigues you, i'll be happy to mail you the file so you can see for yourself (or put it here somehow).

Comment: Sure, send it to so-user at elyobo dot net and I'll have a look.

Answer (score 6):

`^M` is not a newline. `^J` is a newline. `^M` is the character that Windows uses before a newline to show that it causes a line break. It is also called a "carriage return". The escape sequence for it is `\r`.

Comment: To add to this, a profusion of `^M`s is frequently caused by ftp  transferring a text file as binary from a Windows machine (which uses the `^M^J` sequence at the end of each line) to a Unix machine (which uses only `^J`). By using ASCII mode your ftp program will fix this up (but be careful, using ASCII mode on binary data will usually mangle it horribly).